# 'yaml_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

Tags: r

I am trying to run a Kaplan-Meier curve for patients in the Heart dataset that is part of the survival package in R using the model below. Whenever I try to run the code, I am receiving the following error below.

Error: 'yaml_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

Below is the code for the model I am running.

```
model1 <- survfit(Surv(year, event) ~ surgery, data = heart)

summary(model1)
```

Below is the code I am using to plot the Kaplan-Meier curve and the corresponding error.

```
ggsurvplot(
  model1,
  pval = TRUE,
  conf.int = TRUE,
  risk.table = TRUE,
  ggtheme = theme_bw(),
  surv.median.line = "hv",
  palette = c("blue", "#FF0000")
)

Error: 'yaml_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'
```

Comment: You should run `traceback()` after the error; it will say which function is generating the error.  Make sure your packages are up to date, this might be because something has changed.

Comment: I live in hope that, one day, the traceback() will tell me something I, as a mere user, can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also come across this issue, and I found it was due to the `risk.table` that `ggsurvplot` worked after being deleted. I have not found a way to generate a plot with risk table using `ggsurvplot` yet.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the newest version of the 'xfun' package

Answer (score 2):

Go to tools, install packages and type xfun in package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue while generating tables using gt package in a quarto document.
Reinstalling the xfun package and loading it before rendering the document fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Flip and @Reeshu sugested, it worked for me reinstall "xfun" package.
I had first to uninstall manually  the xfun package :
[image]

But later just install the package "xfun" solved all my issues.
I am working with R.4.2.2.